# Prove: Square Matrix Can Be Written As A Sum Of A Symmetric And Skew-Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $C^{n \times n}$ be a square matrix.

Prove that $$C=\frac{1}{2}(C+C^T)+\frac{1}{2}(C-C^T)$$

What I have manage so far is:

a. Let $S$ be a Symmetric Matrix so $S=C+C^T$

b. Let $N$ be a Skew-Symmetric Matrix so $N=C-C^T$

Proof:

$S^t=[C+C^T]^T=C^T+C=S$

$N^t=[C-C^T]^T=-C^T+C=-N$

Comment: I think you mean that you want to prove that the two terms you've divided $C$ into are correctly symmetric and skew-symmetric. Also, your last equality is wrong!

Comment: BTW $N^t=\color{red}{-}N$

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel now its ok?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If $A$ is a square matrix in $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$ then
$$A=\underbrace{\frac12(A+A^t)}_{\text{symmetric matrix}}+\underbrace{\frac12(A-A^t)}_{\text{skew-symmetric matrix}}$$

Comment: Why should it be multiple by $1/2$?

Comment: Without the coefficient $\frac12$ the sum gives $2A$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(A+A^t)_{ij} =A_{ij}+A^t_{ij} = A^t_{ji}+A_{ji} = (A^t+A)_{ji} = (A+A^t)_{ji}$$
Therefore $(A+A^t)$ is symmetric.
$$(A-A^t)_{ij} =A_{ij}-A^t_{ij} = A^t_{ji}-A_{ji} = (A^t-A)_{ji} = -(A-A^t)_{ji}$$
Therefore $(A-A^t)$ is scew-symmetric. Since $$A = \frac12A+\frac12A+\frac12A^t-\frac12A^t=\frac12(A+A^t)+\frac12(A-A^t)$$
$A$ can be Written as a sum of a scew-symmetric and a symmetric Matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Using indicial notation, show that the square matrix can be expressed as the sum of a symmetric and antisymmetric matrix by the decomposition:

> > $$A=\frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}$$