# Square matrix can be written uniquely in the form $A= A_1 + jA_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that every square matrix can be written uniquely in the form $A= A_1 + jA_2$ with $A_1, A_2$ self adjoint.

In this question we have to show for both real and couples matrix case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any n x n matrix A can be written as a sum A = B + C where B is symmetric and C is skew-symmetric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1817421/any-n-x-n-matrix-a-can-be-written-as-a-sum-a-b-c-where-b-is-symmetric-and-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $A_1=\frac {A+A^{*}} 2, A_2= \frac {A-A^{*}} {2j}$. Uniqueness: suppose $A=A_1+jA_2$ where $A_1,A_2$ are self adjoint.  Then $\frac {A+A^{*}} 2=\frac {A_1+jA_2+A_1-jA_2} 2=A_1$. Simialrly, $\frac {A-A^{*}} {2j}=A_2$.

Comment: thanks. I just wanted to know 1 more thing, that $A_1,A_2$ being self adjoint was of no use in the solution?

Comment: @mathamity Self adointness is needed for uniqueness. See my revised answer.

Comment: In Sheldon Axler book on Linear Algebra done right, it says that self adjoint means $T=T^*$. Then by this definition, $A_1=A$ and $A_2=0$? Sorry I am new to this subject.

Comment: $A$ is not given to be self adjoint. You are getting $A_1=A,A_2=0$ by assuming that $A$ is self adjoint.